# What is the best way to switch between projects in Vim?

Tags: vim

I use CtrlP to get around files within a project (which can usually be defined as being a git repo root), but often find myself using `:cd` to switch between different projects which seems unnecessarily time consuming.

I'd like vim to be able to remember different git repo roots I have visited and quickly jump between them.  Once there, all the files in the repo will be available to CtrlP and I can get to where I want.

Is there some way to get what I want with an existing plugin?

Comment: did you try `'autochdir'` option? does it help?

Comment: The best way to switch between projects in Vim is to not switch between projects in Vim. Use separate sessions instead.

Comment: `autochdir` changes the directory once you've already switched files, but I want to change directory in order to more easily switch files

Comment: sessions are great, if there was something that could automatically create a session per git repo that would be close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) then I might have an option for you.

Put the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```vim
set viminfo+=!

if !exists('g:PROJECTS')
  let g:PROJECTS = {}
endif

augroup project_discovery
  autocmd!
  autocmd User Fugitive let g:PROJECTS[fnamemodify(fugitive#repo().dir(), ':h')] = 1
augroup END

command! -complete=customlist,s:project_complete -nargs=1 Project cd <args>

function! s:project_complete(lead, cmdline, _) abort
  let results = keys(get(g:, 'PROJECTS', {}))

  " use projectionist if available
  if exists('*projectionist#completion_filter')
    return projectionist#completion_filter(results, a:lead, '/')
  endif

  " fallback to cheap fuzzy matching
  let regex = substitute(a:lead, '.', '[&].*', 'g')
  return filter(results, 'v:val =~ regex')
endfunction
```

#### Overview

The idea is that anytime fugitive activates a buffer the script stores the project directory path inside a `g:PROJECTS` dictionary. Adding `!` to `'viminfo'` will store capitalized global variables to the viminfo file thereby making the discovered projects persist. Once fugitive discovers a project the `:Project` command can be used to `:cd` to that directory with completion.

#### Notes and Warnings

- I have not tested any of this code. Use as-is.
- Requires Fugitive.vim
- Optionally uses [Projectionist.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) completion if available
- Feel free to add directory paths to `g:PROJECTS` by other means
- Must visit a repository so that it can be discovered
- There is no clean up for missing project directories
- Vim has no concept of "project" so there is only so much that can be done

Comment: Wow, great answer!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Will try this out later today.

Comment: Just tried it out, but fails with: 'Error detected while processing User Auto commands for "Fugitive": E121: Undefined variable: g:PROJECTS'.  I really need to learn vimscript so I can debug stuff like this!

Comment: I have updated the code to ensure that `g:PROJECTS` exists. Please try it out again

Comment: Nice, works like a dream. Added `nmap <Leader>p :Project<Space>` to my .vimrc.  Wish I could give you more +1s!

Comment: @jazmit, thank you. I am glad you like it. I encourage you to use it for awhile and make any necessary tweaks (like checking for deleted projects). I just want to make sure the fuzzy completion is working for you as it is a bit rough.

Comment: I've been using it at work today and so far the completion has been OK.. am looking into projectionist now as I haven't used that before.

Answer (score 2):

Try [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter): when you enter a buffer it automatically changes directory to the buffer's "root" (e.g. git repo root) directory.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks) tip suggests using uppercase marks as 'file bookmarks'.

> For example, open your `.vimrc`, press `mV`, and close Vim. The next time you want to edit your `.vimrc`, just press `'V` to open it.

Comment: This is useful, but I'm looking for something automatic so I don't have to remember to set a mark for every git repo I have (and I have more than 26!)

Answer (score 1):

Just put two project in a new directory, and open Vim in this directory, then you can use ctrlP to open file in both projects.

If you don't want to move the project, create soft link and put them in one directory.